# oracle access on vmware fusion

Tags: networking, oracle, windows-server-2003-r2, vmware-fusion, osx-snow-leopard

I'm running snow leopard and I'm doing some development that requires some network knowledge.
I've installed vmware fusion 3.0 and I've set up a virtual machine with windows 2003 server.

I need to mimic the exact configuration of another server in the network, so I really need to run the versions I'll be mentioning here. Besides, I set up two network configurations on the VM: one NAT config (so that I can have internet access) and one host-only config (because I need to use another server's mac adress and my local area network might have a problem with it)

From the installation of windows 2003, I then installed oracle 10.2.0.1. During the installation I received a warning about the primary ip-address of the system being dhcp assigned, but I ignored it (maybe it was a mistake)...

Now, from experience, unless the DHCP assigned address changes, I should be able to access the guest system's database from the host system, so I went to safari and tried to access the oracle em.

As it turns out, because my computer is on a company network, the company's DNS doesn't know about the virtual machine, unless of course I switch to a bridged network config. However, I don't want to do that because I don't to mix up the domains.

So I guess the question is, how can I define my own dns or router, or whatever it is that I need to define so that whenever I try the guest system's ip address form the host, it will use the vmnet1 or vmnet8 interface define by vmware and bypass the dns configuration of my local area network.

I'd also like to know what to do incase I want to change ip addresses on the guest machine without having oracle go haywire (I've noticed a few folders on the structure which are specific for the very first IP Address)...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS has nothing to do with the network architecture.  It's just a name lookup service if you don't have the IP.  If you don't bridge the virtual network interface, the network routers will have to be configured to use the system as a gateway to the virtual subnet.  There's no reason you can't create another domain in the DNS for the IP of the virtual host no matter how it's connected.

Comment: I undertand that... still, trying to ping the hostname directly doesn't return anything unless I add one entry to my hosts file...